# How to create a .bat file that copies the specific user account folder on a server?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7, usb

I'm trying to create a autorun usb that copies a user profile data folder in Windows 7 with the code below:

```
"@echo off
:: variables
/min
SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
echo off
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\pictures" "%drive%\all\My pics"
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites" "%drive%\all\Favorites"
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\videos" "%drive%\all.\vids"
@echo off 
cls"
```

I don't want to copy the files from the current user but from another user on the server without being logged into the one I want to target. The path is "C:/Users/Adam" but I don't know how to get the code to target the specific user folder and copy it to my usb. How would the code be written or is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You may get away with this:

```cmd
@Echo Off
Set "usrDir=C:\Users\Adam"
Set "prgOpt=/D /E /C /I /H /R /Y"
If Not Exist "%~dp0all\" Exit/B
For %%A In (Favorites Pictures Videos) Do (Set _=%%A
    If Exist "%usrDir%\%%A\" (
        Call XCopy "%usrDir%\%%A\*.*" "%~dp0all\%%_:~,3%%%%_:~-1%%\" %prgOpt%))
```

It will likely have to be **Run as administrator** and you may need to already have a directory named **all** in the root of the USB drive which also hosts this script.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to copy a specific User profile password data or profile data while logged into another Admin account? Like say that im logged into an account that is the Owner and has all the privileges of the Administrator account "C:\Users\Owner" and I want to copy the Password and account data for the Administrator account. Is that possible @Compo? @Compo

Comment: I would generally suggest not, _(unless you are accessing it from a non NTFS system)_. And even then you wouldn't be able to get anything other than the file the password is saved in and then crack it to get the actual password from it

Comment: So I wouldnt be able to copy the password file and i would just be able to copy the folder its in without the file or I would get the password folder with the password file? @Compo

Comment: Because this is the last part to my Programmer class project and its the only thing I've been struggling with is this code. @Compo

Comment: The login passwords are usually, _(or at least used to be)_, stored within the "%__APPDIR__%CONFIG\sam" file. There shouldn't be any reason why that file would be held back in your copy process.

Comment: So what would the full coding be? Do I get rid of any of the " Favorite, Picture, etc.." code from your previous code you posted? @Compo